# Definition with Euclidean domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a Euclidean domain and let $A$ be an ideal of $R.$ Then there exists an element $a_0 \in A$ such that $A$ consists of all $a_0x$ as $x$ ranges over $R.$

I found the above theorem statement a bit unclear. When I read it, I interpret it as "Let $R$ be an Euclidean domain. Then $R$ is also a principal ideal domain." Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct that's what they're saying.

Comment: @jgon thanks for the clarification